# ListBox items not displaying

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox

so i am working on a Windows Phone 7 application, and i am having a problem, normally in my other WPF/WinForm applications this code would work but here on Wphone 7 i am receiving a problems, i created data class:

```
public class AlarmTemplate
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Activated { get; set; }

    public AlarmTemplate(string name, string time, string activated)
    {
        Name = name;
        Time = time;
        Activated = new BitmapImage
                        {UriSource = new Uri("Images/alarm_" + activated + ".png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)};
    }

}
```

Next thing read dad, also i tried with hard coding data and its not working:

```
private List<AlarmTemplate> _templateList = new List<AlarmTemplate>();

private void PopulateList()
    {
        using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (!storage.FileExists("file.txt"))
                return;

            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(storage.OpenFile("file.txt", FileMode.Open)))
            {
                var s = reader.ReadInt32();
                for (var i = 0; i < s; i++)
                {
                    _templateList.Add(new AlarmTemplate(reader.ReadString(), reader.ReadString(),
                                                        reader.ReadString()));
                }
            }
        }
        lbAlarms.ItemsSource = _templateList;
}
```

Here is xaml:

```
<ListBox Height="176.135" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,567.164,0,0" Name="lbAlarms" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" Foreground="#FFFFC7C7" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="Transparent" AllowDrop="False" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#00900707" Grid.Row="1" Hold="lbAlarms_Hold">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Height="52" Orientation="Horizontal" Name="spList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Margin="0,329,0,0" UseLayoutRounding="False">
                    <Image Height="52" Name="imTStatus" Stretch="Uniform" Width="73" Margin="10,0,0,0" UseLayoutRounding="False" Source="{Binding Activated}" />
                    <StackPanel Height="52" Name="spHolder" Width="300" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" UseLayoutRounding="False">
                        <TextBlock Height="26" Name="tbTTime" Text="{Binding Time}" Foreground="Black" FontFamily=".\Fonts\Nokia.ttf#Nokia" TextAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" Width="230" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" UseLayoutRounding="False" />
                        <TextBlock Height="26" Name="tbTName" Text="{Binding Name}"  Foreground="Black" FontFamily=".\Fonts\Nokia.ttf#Nokia" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="297" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`? I've found this is a signficant difference between WPF and Silverlight when it comes to data binding.

Comment: Yes i did, no difference

Comment: if `_templateList` is really contains items, than issue in another place. Show another code, please

Comment: Check `Height`, `Margin`, `Foreground` properties. Make sure that list and items are visible on the screen

Comment: I agree with @Ku6opr, margins look very suspicious (`Margin="0,567.164,0,0"`). Also you will probably not see the image because you are binding the `ImageSource` to a `BitmapImage` whereas you should be binding to a `string` property representing a Uri to the image resource.

Comment: Ku6opr, i tried few things with it before i posted this, only didn't check margin actually, will report after check

Comment: It's neither, after some debugging looks like lbAlarms.ItemsSource = _templateList;
doesn't pass item source...

Comment: @dmusial: You can definetly bind BitmapImage (and any other class inheriting from ImageSource) to an <Image> object.

Comment: @nikolaMM94: You are setting the `lbAlarms.ItemsSource` explicitly, but you also have a binding expression for the ItemSource in Xaml. Which did you intend to use?

Comment: What is the error you receive ?

Comment: There are no errors, @HiTech Magic, i dont believe that is problem, as i change its behaivor, i will try it out now

Comment: You are correct. The binding is ignored as the explicit set overrides it. The actual problem is your black-on-black text as I was able to get your example working with the code unchanged. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working (I noticed the scrollbar was present on the right), but your text colour is black on black so not very visible.

**Get rid of the TextBlock colour** `Foreground="Black"` :)

*Note, your margin means your listbox is very small at the bottom of the page, less than 1 item high, so you might want to change that as well.*

Comment: Haha, thanks a lot, that was not a problem, but close, "StackPanel" had margins with 200 or smth from top which made it need to scroll, since i never tried scrolling i couldn't see it, after modifications it work's great now :), thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<AlarmTemplate> _templateList = new List<AlarmTemplate>();
public List<AlarmTemplate> TemplateList 
{
     get { return _templateList; }
     set { _templateList = value; }
}
```

and set the binding to TemplateList.

Comment: Appropriate improvement, but does not make a difference in this case as the example is not actually using the binding for the list. The existing code actually works as-is, but the items are hidden by the layout issues.